# What events are invoked once the controls Loaded events already fired?

Tags: wpf, events

My windows has many `ListBox`es that load their items in the `Loaded` event. After they are all loaded I have to run a method. I found out that the `Grid` `Loaded` event happens before its controls `Loaded`. What method will fire once after that?

Comment: There is no Load event in WPF.  Are you actually talking about winforms?  In general, use the constructor to initialize stuff.

Comment: @Hans I updated the question to reflect the correct name of the event: `Loaded`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this not answers the title question, it does solve my problem.

- The `Initialized` events are fired prior the `Loaded` events.
- When you have `TabControl` it will fire a `TabItem`'s controls `Loaded` event every time the `SelectedIndex` changes

Knowing that I:

1. replaced every `Loaded` event by a `Initialized` one and
2. created a `Loaded` event for the `MainWindow` that will run after all `Initialized`